# Curl with Post not working Php ?

Tags: php, curl, libcurl

well the problem is the simple this today not working !

```
<?php

function cload($url, $got = array()){

//include(MDL.'socket_adapter.php');
$user_agent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:5.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/5.0";

$default_options = array(
    'data'          => 'og',
    'post_data'        => false,
    'referer'        => false,
    'cookie'           => false,
    'auth'             => false,
    'proxy'           => false,
    'pauth'           => false,
    'returndata'      => true,
);

foreach($default_options as $opt=>$value) {
if(!empty($default_options[$opt])) {$got[$opt] = $value;    }
//if(!empty($got[$opt])) {$got[$opt] = $value;      }
}

//echo "<hr>";      print_r($got);      echo "<hr>";

$curl = curl_init();
//if(strstr($referer,"://")){
//curl_setopt ($curl, CURLOPT_REFERER, $got['referer']);}
curl_setopt ($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt ($curl, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $user_agent);
curl_setopt ($curl, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);
if(isset($got['returndata'])){
curl_setopt ($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
}else{
curl_setopt ($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, false);
}
curl_setopt ($curl, CURLOPT_ENCODING, 'gzip, deflate');
curl_setopt ($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);

    if(isset($got['post_data'])){ curl_setopt($curl ,CURLOPT_POST , true);
    curl_setpot($curl ,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS ,$got['post_data']); }
    if(isset($got['referer'])) curl_setopt($curl,CURLOPT_REFERER, $got['referer']);
    if(isset($got['cookie'])){ if($got['cookie'] == "0"){
    curl_setopt($curl ,CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, TBP."cookie.txt"); }//If ever needed...
    else{
    curl_setopt($curl ,CURLOPT_COOKIE, $got['cookie']); }}


    $custom_headers = array();
    $custom_headers[] = "Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8";
    $custom_headers[] = "Pragma: no-cache";
    $custom_headers[] = "Cache-Control: no-cache";
    $custom_headers[] = "Accept-Language: en-us;q=0.7,en;q=0.3";
    $custom_headers[] = "Accept-Charset: utf-8,windows-1251;q=0.7,*;q=0.7";
    if(isset($url_parts['user']) and isset($url_parts['pass'])) {
        $custom_headers[] = "Authorization: Basic ".base64_encode($url_parts['user'].':'.$url_parts['pass']);
    }elseif(isset($got['auth'])){
    $uj = explode(":",$got['auth']); $custom_headers[] = "Authorization: Basic ".base64_encode($uj[0].':'.$uj[1]); }
    if(isset($got['pauth'])){
        curl_setopt($curl ,CURLOPT_PROXYUSERPWD ,$pauth); }
    if(isset($got['proxy'])){
        curl_setopt($curl ,CURLOPT_PROXY ,$proxy); }

    curl_setopt($curl ,CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $custom_headers);
    //curl_setopt($curl, CURLINFO_HEADER_OUT, true);

    $response = curl_exec($curl);
    $info = curl_getinfo($curl);// , CURLINFO_HEADER_OUT); 
curl_close ($curl);

//echo "<hr>";  echo $info; echo "<hr>";

   return $response; }

   ?>
```

now when i am using this code :

```
<?php
$cv = load('https://localhost/a/ac.php?a=io',array('cookie' => $fbcook,'referer' => $ref,'post_data' => 'odl=lop&isi=837&io'));
echo $cv;
?>
```

but i am getting error :

> Fatal error: Call to undefined function curl_setpot() in C:\xampp\htdocs\a\mack\curl.php on line 41

Please help me ! why this happning this line 42 indicates this line `curl_setpot($curl ,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS ,$got['post_data']); }`

thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When a function of cURL is undefined, then it is most likely that cURL is not available.

However, I think that you meant `curl_setopt()`.

Answer (score 5):

simple typo: curl_setpot should be curl_setopt

Comment: I think I really want there to be a method called curl_setpot().

Comment: bit of a green thumb are you?

Answer (score 3):

`curl_setpot` should be `curl_setopt`.

Answer (score 2):

You use xampp so you need to activate curl lib by following these steps:

1. Locate XAMPP install directory
2. Open `php/php.ini` (probably C:\xampp\php\php.ini
   or C:\program files\apachefriends\xampp\php\php.ini)
3. Do a search for the word ‘curl’ and uncomment (remove the leading semicolon) that line.  Before removing: `;extension=php_curl.dll`.  After removing: `extension=php_curl.dll`
4. Save and close
5. Open `apache/bin/php.ini` (probably C:\xampp\apache\php.ini
   or C:\ program files\apachefriends\xampp\apache\php.ini)
6. Search for curl, uncomment as before (step 3)
7. Save and close
8. Do not forget to restart Apache

Good luck